# How to connect to IBMQ from Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit

I have a problem with connecting on `IBMQ` from `jupyter`, by typing :

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
IBMQ.save_account('Token')
IBMQ.load_account()
```

i tried many different code but nothing worked. I uninstalled `Qiskit`, then i reinstall it and it still don't work.

If you have an idea of what is happening, please tell me

Comment: Hello! What error message are you getting?

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-71d0c65a1df2> in <module>
----> 1 IBMQ.save_account('Token')
TypeError: _init_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'

Comment: I upgrade qiskit-ibmq-provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try running `IBMQ.delete_account()` to remove any old/incorrect credentials that may have accidentally got stored. Then check you have the most up to date versions of all the qiskit packages, especially IBM Q provider which should be on 0.4.1. If the packages need updating run `pip install --upgrade qiskit`.

Once this has finished, run `IBMQ.save_account(token)` to save the credentials again. After this you should be able to run `IBMQ.load_account()`

Comment: I upgrade qiskit-ibmq-provider, but the annaconda prompt told me that the version is incompatible : ERROR: qiskit 0.13.0 has requirement qiskit-ibmq-provider==0.3.3, but you'll have qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.4.3 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: qiskit-ibmq-provider
  Found existing installation: qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.3.3
    Uninstalling qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.3.3:
      Successfully uninstalled qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.3.3
Successfully installed qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.4.3

Comment: So does it work or does it fail when you try to use it?